# Deploying variants of a primary site up to a remote server using Docker

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose

I have two variations of a site based off a primary enrollment site. Currently a running demo of the primary enrollment site is set up and running on a remote server using docker. I'm trying to figure out what steps are needed to move both enrollment site variants A and B up to the remote server for testing and review purposes.

The first variation (branch A) was built from the primary app as master and the second (branch B) was built as a very small variation on the initial vairant, A (think a single file updated from branch A).

So far I understand that I'll have to set up a unique database for both A and B for docker to store app data depending on which enrollment site is running (e.g., enroll-db-A and enroll-db-B). Running both sites from this host will also require specifying a unique port on the dockerfile and docker-compose file since the plan is to keep the primary demo site available through the server's default port.

What I'm confused about is how to actually move the files needed for both variants up to the remote server. Because I obviously want to minimize the number of files needed to transfer up to the remote to handle serving all our sites, and because both variants A and B both largely depend on files from the primary enrollment app root, is it sufficient to simply move all the updated and necessary config files for A and B into new directories on the remote server where the directory for the primary enrollment site is located one level up as the parent of each variant directory?

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase my manager; there's probably some way to make this work, though it's not worthwhile.

My concern in posting this mostly had to do with the apparent number of redundant files that would be pushed up to the remote web server after creating two, simple variants on an original. For our demonstration purposes, having two highly similar repos in addition to the original base loaded on to the web server is not a significant concern.

So, for now, my need to have this question answered can be deferred indefinitely.